# Eclipse IDE C changes file locations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

This has happened **many** times on many projects and it makes development difficult!

I work with a group of engineers. I often import a project someone else has saved into, say:

`c:\git\newproject`

The files are there in "c:\git\newproject", so I start code development, doing builds etc.

But my changes are not in "c:\git\newproject"! (?) Instead they are in

`c:\Users\<myname>\<workspace name>\newproject`

WTF? *The builds will be there too*.  So I look in the project resources. It says:

`PROJECT_LOC  "c:\Users\<myname>\<workspace>\newproject"`

No, that's wrong. I can't push that! Why was it set this way? How can I change it?

As you can tell, I'm getting very frustrated. It's happened to me many times and no one I talk to has any idea why.

Comment: You obviously imported the projects via the _Existing Projects into Workspace_ import wizard with the option _Copy projects into workspace_. Better use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ which also works for non-Eclipse projects.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Yes, I used the existing project import wizard. It's how I've been doing it for years. Did not even know you could do a File->Open on it.
Thanks so much! 

Answer (score 0):

You obviously imported the projects via the ***Existing Projects into Workspace*** import wizard with the option ***Copy projects into workspace***.

**Better** use ***File > Open Projects from File System...*** which also works for non-Eclipse projects.